# Haskell type constructor in generic function

Tags: haskell, generics, lava

I'm digging around in the Haskell Lava HDL system and am stuck in
understanding 
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chalmers-lava2000-1.6.1/docs/src/Lava-Vhdl.html#writeVhdl

Can someone tell me what function `(var "inp")` in `writeVhdl`resolves to?

Function `var` is not defined yet and seems to be generated with some **meta-programming** that is not familiar to me in `class Constructive` in   http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chalmers-lava2000-1.6.1/docs/src/Lava-Generic.html#line-253 .

Function `var` seems to act like a **constructor**. How is this mechanism working?

The input to `writeVhdl` is a circuit description like

```
halfAdd (a, b) = (sum, arry)
  where
    sum = xor2 (a, b)
    arry = and2 (a, b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone tell me what function (var "inp") in writeVhdlresolves to?

It depends on what you pass to `writeVhdl` 2nd argument, namely `circ`. The type of its argument (if I read that correctly) is exactly the type that gets returned by `var "foo"`.

You can observe expression types in `ghci` by typing `:t some expression`. Try loading your code into GHCi session and play with `:t` command.

Comment: ```:t halfAdd``` yields  ```halfAdd :: (Signal Bool, Signal Bool) -> (Signal Bool, Signal Bool)```.  I asked this question also on #haskell irc and got some insight there. User dmjio extracted it into a gist: https://gist.github.com/dmjio/36a394ff36e382b8f9da53ec1687acb2